# Personal library for html/css/js components

Tags: javascript, html, css, components

I have been working as a frontend developer for a couple of months now and have realized that alot of design components repeat itself between projects, an example is boxes. For almost every project I have done this far there has been boxes (productboxes, cta:s, staff etc.) and every time I spend an hour or two to build them from scratch. I could of course look through my old projects to se where I used a similar box before but looking through all the old repos for the best fit takes almost as long time as building from scratch. So my question is there is an application for storing snippets kind of like codepen / jsfiddle but with focus on sorting and tagging up the snippets. For example if I needed boxes I could go to boxes and all boxes I have added could be scrolled through on one page. I feel that both me and the designer could have use of this, especially in projects that have a tight schedule.

I have tried to Google it but I haven't been able the find the right keyword.

Comment: Have you checked out [Bit](https://bitsrc.io/)?

Comment: No I haven't, sounds really promising. Will try it out today, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Fractal](https://fractal.build/) which is exactly what you need. With Fractal you can build your own HTML component library to re-use your components with a nice interface. It's worth to try it out.

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting